# Hugo displays what appears to be properly formatted dates as "1 Jan 0001"

Tags: hugo

I have front-material that looks like:

```
---
title: "example"
date: 2017-02-09T19:33:35-8:00
draft: false
---
```

My `single.html` displays the date like so:

```
      Updated: <time datetime="{{ .Date }}">{{ .Date.Format "2 Jan 2006" }}</time>
```

For some reason, when running `hugo server` and viewing this page, the date is displayed as:

```
Updated: 1 Jan 0001
```

What boggles my mind is, here is a front-matter for a page that *does* work:

```
---
title: "working example"
date: 2019-01-08T18:16:47-08:00
draft: false
---
```

To my eye, the two example dates are identical in format.

Even *weirder*: If I copy/paste from the working example, to the non-working example, and then manually swap out the proper dates, the non-working example works!

What is happening? **Why aren't my dates displaying properly, except when they inexplicably are?**

EDIT: I have tried copy/pasting portion by portion to see if some specific aspect of the string is bad, to no avail. Only when I copy/paste the whole thing, and then manually re-type the dates, does it work. Weirder: if I copy/paste the good format to the "bad," then copy/paste the *dates* from bad to good, it works. I suspected maybe a weird unicode character or something, now I have no idea.

Comment: what version of hugo?

Comment: `Hugo Static Site Generator v0.53 linux/amd64 BuildDate: 2018-12-24T12:58:43Z
`

Comment: Hmmm... maybe tab vs space between the ':' and the date string? trailing space?  I notice the offset has a leading zero in one case but not the other? I think ISO 8601 requires the leading zero, but not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just confirmed with my own website,

The time/date string must follow the [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). This includes the timezone offset having two digits in the hours.

Note that the offset is optional - it doesn't have to be there. But if it is, it must be `[+-]HH:MM`

```
# bad
date: 2017-02-09T19:33:35-8:00
# good
date: 2017-02-09T19:33:35-08:00
```